# Configuring Elastic Search cluster with machines of different capacity(CPU, RAM) for rolling upgrades

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, high-availability

Due to cost restrictions, I only have the following types of machines at disposal for setting up an ES cluster.

1. Node A: Lean(w.r.t. CPU, RAM) Instance
2. Node B: Beefy(w.r.t. CPU,RAM) Instance
3. Node M: "Leaner than A"(w.r.t. CPU, RAM) Instance

Disk-wise, both A and B have the same size.

My plan is to set up Node A and Node B acting as Master Eligible, Data node and Node M as Master-Eligible Only node(no data storing).
Because the two data nodes are NOT identical, what would be the implications?

I am going to make it a cluster of 3 machines only for the possibility of Rolling Upgrades(current volume of data and expected growth for few years can be managed with vertical scaling and leaving the default no. of shards and replica would enable me to scale horizontally if there is a need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need for your machines to have the same specs. You will need 3 master-eligible nodes not just for rolling-upgrades, but for high availability in general.

If you want to scale horizontally you can do so by either creating more indices to hold your data, or configure your index to have multiple primary and or replica shards. Since version 7 the default for new indices is to get created with 1 primary and 1 replica shard. A single index like this does not really allow you to schedule horizontally.

**Update:**

With respect to load and shard allocation (where to put data), Elasticsearch by default will simply consider the amount of storage available. When you start up an instance of Elasticsearch, it introspects the hardware and configures its threadpools (number of threads & size of queue) for various tasks accordingly. So the number of available threads to process tasks can vary. If I‘m not mistaken the coordinating node (the node receiving the external request) will distribute indexing/write requests in a round-robin fashion, not taking a load into consideration. Depending on your version of Elasticsearch, this is different for search/read requests where the coordinating node will leverage adaptive replica selection, taking into account the load/response time of the various replicas when distributing requests.

Besides this, sizing and scaling is a too complex topic to be answered comprehensively in a simple response. It typically also involves testing to figure out the limits/boundaries of a single node.

BTW: the number of default primary shards got changed in v7.x of Elasticsearch, as too much oversharding was one of the most common issues Elasticsearch users were facing. A “reasonable” shard size is in the tens of Gigabytes.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the response.  
I was not aware of the change in defaults (In one of the existing setups, the default is 5 primary shards and 1 replica).  
While I understand the benefit of having 3 master-eligible node w.r.t HA under network partition, and scaling horizontally by creating indices with over-allocated shards, my question was more w.r.t load on the 2 nodes during indexing and querying. Because, Node A is lean, **would ES take this into consideration** while answering queries Or, a query would hit equal number of shards on both Node A and Node B = bottleneck?

Comment: Trying to understand what happens behind the scenes and not just an Yes/No.  TIA for any insights.

Comment: Ok, you seem to be on an Elasticsearch version prior to 7.x, where the default number of primary shard was 5. I will update my answer with a comment about load.